# how to override a jquery hint with mysql echo

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

how do i override jquery hint if there is a mysql echo in that textfield.
Presently I have a jquery hint but when the field has a value in mysql and I echo it the jquery hint is still present.

php jquery hint script

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    //Shows the title in the text box, and removes it when modifying it
    $('input[title]').each(function (i) {
        $(this).val($(this).attr('title')).addClass('hint');

        $(this).focus(function () {
            if ($(this).val() == $(this).attr('title')) {
                $(this).val('').removeClass('hint');
            }
        });

        $(this).blur(function () {
            if ($(this).val() == '') {
                $(this).val($(this).attr('title')).addClass('hint');
            }
        });
    });

    //Clear input hints on form submit
    $('form').submit(function () {
        $('input.hint').val('');
        return true;
    });
});
```

form text field

```
<input type="text" name="name" id="name" title="insert here" value=<?php echo $row3['name']?> />
```

Comment: **You need to indent your code.** Really. Besides that... is there a reason why you don't use the `placeholder` attribute? It's supported in all modern browsers and for older browsers there is https://github.com/mathiasbynens/jquery-placeholder to make it work.

Answer (score 1):

Replace `$(this).val($(this).attr('title')).addClass('hint');` with the following code:

```
if(!$(this).val()) {
    $(this).val($(this).attr('title')).addClass('hint');
}
```

However, you should really consider using the `placeholder` attribute. To make it work in older browsers, simply add the script from https://github.com/mathiasbynens/jquery-placeholder

Comment: Thanks worked a treat. What kind of browser versions (IE) will this not work on? Also how would I change the colour of 'insert text' but not the textfield colour?